# How to reset a WPF control's default opacity toggling via IsEnabled after setting opacity explictly?

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity, reset, isenabled

When I disable a control (button), it is so dark that it is very hard to read the text.

So I am using an extension method to set the opacity to 1.0 (100%) so it can be read easily, even when disabled:

```
public static void IsEnabledSpecial(this System.Windows.UIElement control, bool isEnabled) {
    control.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
    control.Opacity = 1.0;          // This makes a disabled control more readable
}
```

Normally, when opacity is not explicitly set for a WPF control, it appears to toggle between 1.0 (100%) when the control is enabled and 0.35 (35%) when the control is disabled.

Once I explicitly set the opacity using the extension method, the control thereafter ceases to toggle between 1.0 and 0.35 when I set IsEnabled *without* the extension method.  It gets "stuck" at 1.0 (100%), even when IsEnabled is set to false;

After I set the opacity, how can I later reset the control to do its normal opacity toggling between 1.0 and 0.35?

Comment: Why don't just define a style for control with a trigger to set opacity when control is disabled?

Comment: @Dennis: I can't use styles/triggers because sometimes I need the opacity to be bright when disabled (so you can read it) and sometimes I need it to be dark when disabled - I change the text in the button as a way of indicating status.  For exmple, I disable the button and say "Waiting for job to finish..." and then re-enable the button when the job is finished.

Comment: Still you should do this in XAML with a style, you are missing ViewModel part in your design. Where you bind to some property IsEnabled={BInding IsWaiting} and then put trigger in a style to react on disabled change or use datatrigger for IsWaiting

Answer (score 0):

The changing of the `Opacity` is being done through triggers. By setting the value directly, you are overriding any value that may be produced by a style or triggers. This is really not the way to go about doing this sort of thing. You should be using styles and triggers of your own.

However, you may be able to achieve what you want simply by clearing the value that is assigned to `Opacity`:

```
control.ClearValue(UIElement.OpacityProperty);
```